# Ayuda con validar un arraylist si esta vacio

Tags: arraylist

tengo un problema y es que no se como validar que un arraylist de objetos no este null, he trabajado arreglos estaticos pero no se como usar los dinamicos.

SI ME PUEDEN AYUDAR CON PSEUDOCODIGO les agradezco.

Comment: Es en java o c#?

Answer (score 4):

En java, comprueba que es null o si el metodo `size()`, que te retorna la cantidad de elemento en array, retorna 0:

```
ArrayList<String> nombres = new ArrayList<String>();

if(nombres == null || nombres.size() == 0)
{
  // el arraylist no tiene valor
}
else{
 // el arraylist tiene valor
}
```

Si es c#, seria igual solo que reemplazias el metodo `size()` por `Count` que te da el total de elemento en el ArrayList:

```
 ArrayList nombres = new ArrayList();

if(nombres == null || nombres.Count == 0)
{
  // el arraylist no tiene valor
}
else{
 // el arraylist tiene valor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tienes que comprobar es si es null, esto se debe a que si es null e intentas comprobar mediante sus métodos si está vacía te dará NullPointerException. En la misma comprobación puedes usar isEmpty() (Java) para verificar si contiene objetos, este método devuelve un boolean

Quedaría así:

```
if(miLista == null || miLista.isEmpty())
{
//lista nula o vacía
}
```

De esta manera si es null se ejecutaría el contenido del if sin preguntar si está vacía porque usamos doble | 
En caso de no ser null ya el if consulta la segunda condición y sabría si está vacía.

Comment: hay algo que no entiendo, ¿Podrían explicarme? ¿Si la lista es null eso no significa necesariamente que está vacía? Es decir, ¿Para qué poner "|" y luego NameOfList.isEmpty()?
¿Con la primera condición no bastaría? Gracias por responder.

Comment: @AndreaArias null y vacío no es lo mismo. Puedes tener una lista con valor null (p.e. si aún no se ha instanciado) y puedes tener una lista con 0 elementos (p.e. si aún no se ha insertado ninguno). El usuario  considera en ambos casos  que la lista está vacía, pero puedes tener una lista sin ser null,  que no contenga ningún elemento y por tanto esté vacía [].